# Concurrently process incoming emails using Apache Camel in a cluster

Tags: java, email, apache-camel, jakarta-mail

I'm evaluating Apache Camel and was wondering whether I can process incoming emails using the [E-Mail Component](http://camel.apache.org/mail.html) in a cluster while guaranteeing that every email is processed only once. I wanna deploy the E-Mail Consumer Endpoint in a cluster, where all cluster nodes process incoming emails from a single IMAP server.

Is this possible using the Email Component or do I have to take care of duplicates myself (e.g. using the [Idempotent Consumer](http://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html) pattern)?